# Слитно или раздельно? 3

Tags: частица-не

...и не использующими обычно не лимитируемое осевое измерение.

Есть правило о словах на **-мый**, которые могут быть и прилагательными и причастиями (если при них в качестве пояснительного слова находится существительное в творительном падеже). В последнем случае такие слова пишутся раздельно. Здесь пояснительного слова нет. Значит, это прилагательное? Ворд слитное написание подчеркивает красным. Как здесь быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь слитное написание НЕ с прилагательным:  **..и не использующими обычно нелимитируемое осевое измерение.**

Пояснение

Лимитировать - переходный глагол несовершенного вида, от него **может** образоваться причастие "не лимитируемые стандартом величины" с раздельным написанием НЕ, но для этого **необходимо обязательное  наличие  зависимого слова в Т.п.**

Почему? Зависимые слова в Т.п. обозначают производителя (инструмент) **реального** действия, при наличии других зависимых слов слово на МЫЙ остается в статусе прилагательного.

(Из правил Розенталя)

Answer (score 1):

> ...и не использующими обычно не лимитируемое осевое измерение.

Контекст слишком мал для понимания фразы.

**Вариант 1.** Эти что-то (или эти кто-то) **обычно не используют** "нелимитируемое осевое измерение".
Здесь уместно слитное написание.

**Вариант 2.** Осевое измерение **обычно не лимитируется.** Тогда в исходной фразе уместнее раздельное написание.

А о чём хотел сказать автор? А бог его знает...

Comment: Я думала, здесь контекст не важен. Могу дать полную фразу: Общетехническая культура фланцевых соединений остановилась перед головастыми болтами и наружными гайками, увеличивающими наружный диаметр фланца и не использующими обычно не лимитируемое осевое измерение.

Comment: Тут слово "обычно" непонятно куда относится. Либо "не использующими обычно", либо "обычно не лимитируемое", скорее второе. Но как это слово влияет на написание? Это ведь не существительное в тв. падеже. Или раз это не существительное здесь действует просто правило наличия любых зависимых слов?

Comment: Alenka, мне контекст не помог. Что такое "осевое измерение", я, к сожалению, не сумел понять. И это несмотря на то, что фланцевыми и др. соединениями занимался не год и не два... А "**головастыми болтами**" меня это предложение так вообще чуть не убило!

Comment: _Alenka: Тут слово "обычно" непонятно куда относится. Либо "не использующими обычно", либо "обычно не лимитируемое", скорее второе._ === КАК ВАРИАНТ --> Если "скорее второе", уберите слово **обычно**: "...и не использующими нелимитируемое осевое измерение". === Если **первое**, переставьте слово **обычно** чуть вперёд: "…и обычно не использующими нелимитируемое осевое измерение". === P.S. Но о каком таком _осевом измерении_ идёт речь, я, к сожалению, пока не понял.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: А кто/что есть "пользователь нелимитируемого осевого измерения"? Те самые головастые болты и наружные гайки? И, скорее всего, корректнее употребить предлог "на", а не "перед". Машинный перевод?

Comment: Версия понимания смысла: "...болты и гайки, на размеры которых отсутствуют ограничения в осевом направлении".

Comment: _Hermit : А кто/что есть пользователь нелимитируемого осевого измерения? Те самые головастые болты и наружные гайки?_ === По строю предложения похоже, что они самые. Но... Если б я понимал и всё остальное в этом предложении...

Comment: Развитие фланцевых соединений остановилось на "головастых болтах и наружных гайках" (в том виде, в котором они были на тот момент времени, который описывает автор). Далее описывается принцип их использования с той точки зрения, с которой их видит автор. Он видит преимущества и недостатки их использования. Предлог **"на"** здесь действительно корректнее, но это не перевод.

Comment: Alenka, ну а что автор понимает под _осевым измерением_ и чем/кем лимитируется это _измерение_? Из текста автора это понятно?

Comment: Я не настолько хорошо разбираюсь в конструкциях, что такое фланцы не знаю. Только сейчас залезла в Википедию. И конечно, что автор имеет в виду, говоря _осевое измерение_, я не понимаю. Но он известный конструктор, и я полагаю, можно ему довериться.